# Sprind data JPA: multiple OneToMany relations query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I can't figure out what is the problem with the following query (it returns no results):

```java
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
   // ...
   @Query("SELECT o FROM Organization o " +
            "JOIN o.establishments e " +
            "JOIN e.buildings b " +
            "WHERE b.id = ?1 ")
   Organization findOrganizationFromBuilding(Long buildingId);
   // ...
}
```

The relations are defined as follows in the corresponding entity classes:

```java
public class Organization extends AbstractEntity {
  // ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Establishment> establishments;
  // ...
}

public class Establishment extends AbstractEntity {
  // ...
  @ManyToMany(cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
     name = "establishment_buildings",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "establishment_id"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "buildings_id"))
  private Set<Building> buildings;

  @ManyToOne
  private Organization organization;
  // ...
}

public class Building extends AbstractEntity {
   // ...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "buildings", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Establishment> establishments;
   // ...
}
```

It is supposed to run the RAW SQL query as follows (which returns the only result) and works:

```sql
SELECT o.* from organization o
inner join establishment e on o.id = e.organization_id
inner join establishment_buildings eb on e.id = eb.establishment_id
inner join building b on eb.buildings_id = b.id
where b.id = <some id>;
```

I activated show-sql in `application.properties` and here is the generated query:

```sql
select organizati0_.id as id1_34_, ... other fields
 
 from organization organizati0_ 
 inner join organization_establishments establishm1_ on organizati0_.id=establishm1_.organization_id 
 inner join establishment establishm2_ on establishm1_.establishments_id=establishm2_.id 
 inner join establishment_buildings buildings3_ on establishm2_.id=buildings3_.establishment_id 
 inner join building building4_ on buildings3_.buildings_id=building4_.id where building4_.id=?
```

I have no idea why there is an extra `INNER JOIN` on the table `organization_establishments`, - there is no association declared in the `Organization` entity...
This table `organization_establishents` does exist in the DB, but it is really weird to see it being used without any declaration or reference of an entity class.

More of that, I tried to replace the above query with a native one as follows:

```java
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
        "o.company_number as companyNumber " +
        "from organization o " +
        "inner join establishment e on o.id = e.organization_id " +
        "inner join establishment_buildings eb on e.id = eb.establishment_id " +
        "inner join building b on eb.buildings_id = b.id " +
        "where b.id = ?1",
        nativeQuery = true)
    OrganizationCompanyNumber findByBuildingId(Long buildingId);

   // ...
   interface OrganizationCompanyNumber {
      String getCompanyNumber();
   }
}
```

what generated the following query:

```sql
SELECT o.company_number as companyNumber from organization o 
inner join establishment e on o.id = e.organization_id 
inner join establishment_buildings eb on e.id = eb.establishment_id 
inner join building b on eb.buildings_id = b.id where b.id = ?
```

but returned `NULL`. Nevertheless, running the same query in PGAdmin does return a single result.

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to use [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) `@OneToMany` (Organization - Establishment) you should refer the inverse side by `mappedBy`.

So, try to correct your mapping in this way:

```
@Entity
public class Organization extends AbstractEntity {
   // ...
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "organization", orphanRemoval = true)
   @JsonIgnore
   private Set<Establishment> establishments;

   // 
}

@Entity
public class Establishment extends AbstractEntity {

   // ...

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
   private Organization organization;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The modification didn't fix the NPE, but I found that it was due to some previous queries modifying other related to the `Building` entity deletion. I think that for some reason one of these operations probably has an impact on the above query resulting in the `NULL` result. After commenting them out, the result contained the right `Organization`. I'll have to analyze them one by one to figure out the reason of that behavior.

Comment: The above changes should fix `extra INNER JOIN on the table organization_establishments`